# Can we use layout_scrollFlags in other views except Toolbar and AppbarLayout

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have start working on Android material design support library, and as a newbie I have some confusions. And, need your help. :)

1) Is it possible to use `layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` with views like `SearchView`?

2) I want a `SearchView` just below the `Toolbar`. I achieved it using `AppBarLayout`, but I want to scroll the `SearchView` not `Toolbar` on scrolling the content below `SearchView`. Using `layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` on `SearchView` doesn't works.

3) Can we use more than one `AppBarLayout` in `CoordinatorLAyout` and `Toolbar` in `AppBarLayout`?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible but you need to enable nested scrolling for your search view.

```
SearchView searchViewRef;
NestedScrollingChildHelper mNestedScrollingChildHelper = new NestedScrollingChildHelper(searchViewRef);
mNestedScrollingChildHelper.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
```